# Make uTorrent display seeders and leeches

Tags: utorrent

Is there any way to make the current version (3.1.3) of utorrent display the number of seeders and leeches like the old utorrent use to?? 
What will happen if a torrent has no seeders will utorrent notify you of this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Right click on the bar with the titles of the various columns, and select "Seeds" "Peers" or "Seeds/Peers" - Peers should be the same as leeches